# Finding the admin page for my router

Tags: router

I have a Hawking HWR-258 wireless router sitting on my network acting as a switch. I want to start using the wireless part of it, so I went searching for the admin page. No luck. According to various websites the default IP is 192.168.1.254, but that doesn't bring up anything. It could be that my network seems to be using the 10.1.10* ip set? I can get into the Comcast box fine, and the page that lists local computers on the network doesn't list anything.

Any ideas how I could get to the admin page?

To clarify:

[Computer] <-> [Hawking Box] <-> [Comcast Box]

Here is the tracert to my default gateway:

```
>tracert 10.1.10.1
>
>Tracing route to www [10.1.10.1]
>over a maximum of 30 hops:
>
>  1    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  www [10.1.10.1]
>
```

Comment: `cmd /k ipconfig`

Comment: using that brings up some ipv6 addresses, which I'm not really sure how to use.

Comment: If the nework is [Your Computer]->[Router]->[Comcast Box], use tracert [Comcast-IP] to see the hops to get to the Comcast box.  The router IP should be in there.

Comment: That doesn't seem to show anything. Is it possible that my Hawking box is acting like a dumb switch somehow?

Comment: `tracert google.com`?

Comment: @Hello71: That doesent seem to show anything interesting.

Comment: Could you post the results of the tracert?  Any information is helpful.  Also specify where the Comcast's IP is.

Comment: If your computer is using 10.1.10.1 and you are trying to reach a router on whole different network (192.168.1.254), it will fail. You should directly connect to the router you want to change and remove your computer from the existing network. You should be able to reach it fine then. You will then want to disable DHCP and change the IP of the router to something on the same subnet as your existing router, but outside the DHCP range.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can get to the admin page if it is acting as a switch. I have seen that happen to a wireless router which was also being used as a switch, to transmit the wired connection over wireless. In that case, each client connecting to the router would actually request an IP from the wired connection, and the router would just sit there, watching, doing nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Run cmd.exe (if you are on Windows) and type `ipconfig`, you should see this line somewhere in the output:

```
Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : xxx.xxx.x.x (ex. 192.168.1.1)
```

That number should be your router's address, assuming your computer is directly connected to it.

On Mac OS or Linux, open up a terminal window and run `route -n` and look for something like this one:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 ra0
0.0.0.0         xxx.xxx.x.x     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 ra0
```

That Gateway number with the `UG` flag (G for gateway) should be your router's ip address.

Comment: I got my router's address(the comcast box that connects to the internet), thats the default gateway. It't the wireless box that sits in-between that I cant find.

Comment: Well, that might be why you can't connect to the router. Try directly connecting to the router with an ethernet cable and re-running the command and trying to connect again.

Comment: [Computer] <-> [Hawking Box] <-> [Comcast Box] is the setup I have. So  I am directly connected to it?

Comment: Try connecting ONLY to the Hawking box and rerunning the command.

Comment: Still nothing. That Hawking box simply doesent seem to exist.

Comment: Have you tried 10.1.10.254?

Comment: Your best bet is probably to find some way to set it back to factory defaults.

Comment: It seems your router is just acting as a switch, and passing every single connection on to your Comcast box no matter what. I don't know what can help other than a factory reset like @OrigamiRobot suggested.

Comment: At this point I think you are right. I tried resetting it, but my attempt dident seem to do anything, so I probably did it wrong. The manual I found dident show how to do it.

Comment: To be clear, the router seems to be acting like a hub.  Sometimes they are called Layer 1 Switches, but I find this misleading.  A hub doesn't do any kind of traffic monitoring.  It just repeats the signal it was given.  I can't imagine why a router would do this since you almost have to manually reset it to get it to do anything else.

Answer (score 1):

If there aren't many devices on your network, try running an IP Scanner.  I prefer Angry IP Scanner http://www.angryip.org/w/Home  It will tell you what IPs are in use on your network.  If you can filter out the IPs you know (other machines, printers, etc) then whatever is leftover should theoretically be your wireless unit.

Was the box installed by Comcast?  If so, they may have set it up in a different mode and its not actually using an IP.  They may have to connect from their side to turn on the wireless functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information you gave, that despite being on the same physical network (all plugged in together), they are on different logical networks.

Pick out a free IP address on your 10.1.10.x network. Then, manually set your computer's IP address to something like 192.168.1.100, and connect to 192.168.1.254 (you may have to reset the device to factory defaults). Then set it to use the free IP address on 10.1.10.x you picked out earlier, and commit the changes. Change your computer back to the 10.1.10.x network.

Connect to the new IP address and configure your wireless.

Comment: It could be that I just cant figure out how to reset the router. I have taken a pencil to it several times, but hasent seemed to do anything.